# Modbus testing on Linux

Tags: linux, uart, modbus

I am having UART which is used as debug console on board. I want to use this UART for some other purpose.

Like running modbus application on UART. What I have done is removed debug console support on the serial port.

connected RS232 to host ubuntu PC and ran simple UART TX/RX application on host and target to confirm UART serial port, which is working.

Now how to confirm modbus over UART on target. I ran sample test application

(unit-test-client/unit-test-server rtu) from libmodbus library, which is not giving any output.

Please suggest a simple modbus test application through which I can confirm that modbus is working.

Comment: Can you explain how are you setting up your tests with *libmodbus*? You need to have **two** serial ports, one for the master on which to run the client and one as a slave for the server. Other than that you just need to edit the source to point to your port names (`/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`, for instance), connect the wires RX to TX and TX to RX and run first the server and then the client. I have used these tests multiple times successfully.

Comment: i have connected RS232 to host(UBUNTU) serial port and modified port name (/dev/ttyUSB0) accordingly in test application and same RS232 cable i have connected to target UART serial port, i have modified the target application port name to /dev/ttyLP0 accordingly and tested. Please correct me.

Comment: That's good, have you compiled both unit tests (client and server) before running them?

Comment: And you might need to have privileges to write on your ports, have you given permissions or run the tests with `sudo`?

Comment: yes, tests are running. But i am not sure what to expect in output as it is bare serial device.

Comment: root@imx8dx_ccu:~# ./unit-test-server rtu
Inside modbus server......................
Opening /dev/ttyLP0 at 115200 bauds (N, 8, 1)
Waiting for a indication...
ERROR Connection reset by peer: read
<05>Quit the loop: Connection reset by peer
root@imx8dx_ccu:~# ./unit-test-server rtu
Inside modbus server......................
Opening /dev/ttyLP0 at 115200 bauds (N, 8, 1)
Waiting for a indication...
ERROR Connection reset by peer: read
<05>Quit the loop: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Opening /dev/ttyUSB0 at 115200 bauds (N, 8, 1)
** UNIT TESTING **
1/1 No response timeout modification on connect: OK

TEST WRITE/READ:
[11][05][01][30][FF][00][8F][59]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<5E><41><30><FF><5E>
Request for slave 94 ignored (not 17)
The responding slave 94 isn't the requested slave 17
Bytes flushed (0)
1/2 modbus_write_bit: 
Line 137: assertion error for 'rc == 1': 
ayl5kor@ayl5kor-VirtualBox:~/Extra/libmodbus/libmodbus/tests$ sudo ./unit-test-client rtu
Opening /dev/ttyUSB0 at 115200 bauds (N, 8, 1
1/1 No response timeout modification on connect: OK

Comment: i have shared outputs of my applications above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199274/discussion-between-marcos-g-and-anikhan).